# Set registry data only for the custom page

Tags: magento-1.9, registry, custompage

I have a custom page created by our module. I am registering a registery in our controller as below

```
Mage::register('customPage', 'customPage');
```

After the visit to this page, while go to the other pages, it's still in registered condition. I need to unset this registery in all other pages. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The Magento registry is not persisted, as in once you are on a new page you will not see those **registry variables still set**. I mainly use the registry to communicate between **controllers** and **blocks**.

but you can `Mage::unregister('customPage')` after using the **registry** value.

Comment: But where to unregister it. My page contents are coming from the index action, there I am registering this variable. But where I can unregister it?

Comment: @SIBHIS you are registering it for using in **block or phtml** after **phtml end** add this code `Mage::unregister('customPage');`